# Did an Imperial Ruling Council member serve as an assistant to Darth Vader?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, darth-vader, rogue-one

In *Rogue One*, a hooded character acts as an assistant to Darth Vader. He kneels before the Sith Lord and informs about the arrival of Director Krennic. Wookieepedia states that his name is **[Vaneé](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Vane%C3%A9)**. Is it possible that he and **[Kren Blista-Vanee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kren_Blista-Vanee)**, an [Imperial Ruling Council](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_Ruling_Council) member in *Return of the Jedi*, are the same character? To me, at least, their appearances look somewhat similar (considering they're some 4 years apart, in the in-universe timeline).

[image]

Comment: On a second thought... disregarding Vaneé's Human nose, he kind of looks like a Muun from the Legends, doesn't he?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Seems unlikely<sup>1</sup>

Kren Blista-Vanee is mentioned in the canon novel *Tarkin*, set fourteen years before *Rogue One*, as a newcomer to the Imperial Ruling Council:

> Fond of wearing flamboyant hats and frequenting the opera, Blista-Vanee was a relative newcomer to the Ruling Council, but had already proven an asset in blazing hyperspace routes into the Deep Core star systems.
>
> <sup>*Tarkin* Chapter 15: "Negative Capability"</sup>

The career trajectory that leads one to transition from the Ruling Council to Vader's lackey over a fourteen year period, only to re-ascend to the Ruling Council within the next four years, boggles my mind; it's astronomically unlikely that they could be the same person.

---

<sup>1</sup> I had initially claimed here that Pablo Hidalgo debunked this claim [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/809187155842994176). Later [tweets](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/812538420887072768) from Hidalgo revealed that I misinterpreted him, so I've removed that section

Comment: Oh great. EVERYONE is Snoke! I'm still holding out hope he's Jar-Jar. Great find, anyway. But where is the name from? Is he on the cast list?

Comment: @DVK-in-exile My favourite part is the tweet Hidalgo is replying to, which is basically "please confirm this guy isn't Snoke, because everybody's going to assume he is anyway and I want to nip this one in the bud"

Comment: @DVK-in-exile He's named in the Visual Guide and [on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3748528/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast). I still haven't seen the film, so I couldn't tell you if he's in the credits or not

Comment: @JasonBaker Hidalgo's statement is clear, thank you for sharing that. However, I kind of disagree with your further thinking. In my opinion, watching over the Lord of the Sith, especially when he's at his weakest, could be considered an honor, even for a member of the Imperial Ruling Council.

Comment: @Essen I very intensely disagree, but if Hidalgo's statement is what swayed you then you may want to unaccept my answer; I recently learned that I misinterpreted him

Answer (score 1):

Novelization merely calls him "Black-cloacked aide" and doesn't name him. The name "Vane*" doesn't appear in the text at all.